# res.render() works in one situation but not in another

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

In the code below, why does `res.render('home');` work, but `res.render('update');` does not?

This is running with Node.js, Express, and Handlebars.

**file structure**

```
myApp
│
├───app.js
│               
├───public
│   │       
│   └───scripts
│           buttons.js
│           
└───views
    │   home.handlebars
    │   update.handlebars
    │   
    └───layouts
            main.handlebars
```

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(express.static('public'));
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
var handlebars = require('express-handlebars').create({defaultLayout:'main'});
app.engine('handlebars', handlebars.engine);
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

app.set('port', 3000);

//*****Routes*************

app.get('/',function(req,res,next){
    res.render('home');
});

app.get('/update', function(req,res,next){
    res.render('update');
});

app.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
    console.log('Express started on http://localhost:' + app.get('port') + '; press Ctrl-C to terminate.');
});
```

**buttons.js**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', bindButtons);

function bindButtons(){
    document.getElementById('Submit').addEventListener('click', sendRequest());
}

function sendRequest() {
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open('GET', 'http://localhost:3000/update');
    req.send();
};
```

**home.handlebars**

```
<h1>Home Page</h1>
<input type="submit" id="Submit">
```

**update.handlebars**

```
<h1>Update Page</h1>
```

**main.handlebars**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Main Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    {{{body}}}
</body>
</html>
```

Clicking the button doesn't load the update page. I am not sure why.

Comment: Have you tried replacing the res.render('update') with a console.log to see if the app.get fires?

Comment: Yup, I put a log in the routes, and they both are firing. Just seems that the res.render() doesn't seem to be doing anything.

Comment: I've never used handlebars so my quick learning spree hasn't helped me any. I'd guess the issue is there, as everything else _looks_ right (for what my knowledge is worth).

Comment: This person seems to have almost the same setup and issue, but their issue was not mine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37670488/cant-get-res-render-to-render-using-os-x-10-11-4-node-js-express3-handlebars

Comment: are you sure update.handlebars is in the right folder?

Comment: Location for `update.handlebars` is `myApp/views/update.handlebars`
Is that correct? `home.handlebars` is in the same folder as well. `app.js` is located directly under `myApp/`

Comment: This may be me being completely off from no handlebar knowledge more than 60 minutes old, but why isn't there any 'handlebars'? I.e., {{}} or {{{}}}?

Comment: You need to set the views folder `app.set('views', 'views');`Then put the views folder in your root folder. And use the full file name `res.render('home.handlebars')`.

Comment: @magreenberg, I attempted what you suggested but no change. I've also include my file structure in the original post.

Comment: @JustinBurgard, I've included my main.handlebars file with the {{{body}}} tag.

Comment: Try removing the () here, after sendRequest:     `document.getElementById('Submit').addEventListener('click', sendRequest () );`

Comment: Gave it a shot, no luck :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is your `sendRequest()` function. You're sending a GET http request to the `/update` page, so it is being rendered, but just not in your browser.

`XmlHttpRequest` is used for sending HTTP requests without leaving the page. It does not tell your browser to navigate to that address.

I think what you want is to tell your browser to navigate to the `/update` page.

For example

```
function sendRequest() {
   window.location = "/update";
};
```

Try that, and it should do what you want.